# Deploying laravel Rest API using apache

Tags: php, laravel, apache, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my project on a server, Its a REST API. the server is running apache and is working properly (I tested it with a hello world script).

My project is in /var/API.
I've moved my public folder from my project to my document root (`/var/www/`).
I've altered my `index.php` document from my laravel project and added it to my document root, along with my `public/.htaccess`. The problem I'm having lies in my altered `index.php` file posted below.

If I run a get API call i get a 404 error in my browser. If I just run the ip for the server itself I get a 500 error.

```
<?php

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

require __DIR__.'/var/API/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/var/API/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the error is?

Comment: whoops sorry I updated the answer

Comment: try removing `__DIR__` just `require  '/var/API/vendor/autoload.php';` and `require_once '/var/API/bootstrap/app.php';`

Comment: no luck it didnt work. I think I may have found a solution. I need to run `php artisan route:cache` but when I do I get an error  `Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.` Im working on fixing it now.

Comment: fixed the issue with `php artisan route:cache` but it didnt solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've moved my public folder from my project to my document root

You should not move the `public` folder from the project, it will break many things. Keep the project structure as is and change your apache `DocumentRoot` to point to the `public` folder.

I would move the project from `/var/API` to `/var/www/API` and change `DocumentRoot` in apache config to be `/var/www/API/public`

Comment: that makes sense. that way I don't need to alter my `index.php`. right? I did that but I'm still having the same error. I also had to alter some of my code and run.
`$ php composer dumpautoload -o
$ php artisan config:cache
$ php artisan route:cache`

Comment: Yes, you don't need to edit `index.php` because by default it expects `vendor` folder to be found next to the `public` folder. Also, if you checked the file `bootstrap/app.php`, you will see Laravel defines the root of the project on which many parts of the application depends. That's why you had to run `config:cache` and `composer dumpautoload`